# How to compare values in two wpf datagrid values if already listed?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datarow, datarowview

am tryied the below code for checking the sid value,there are two datagrid,

In one datagrid,am select a row and send to another datagrid2 with a tabindex am mentioned here.

First time when am sent means,it want to add to datagrid2.Then if am again the same datarow selected from datagrid1 and send means,it want to show "its already listed in datagrid2" --this is my concept

But when am trying the below code its always shows listed in datagrid3,so how to change the code perfectly for my concept???

```
public void sendstudy(string sid, DataRow row)       
{ 

  this.datatableobject.Rows.Add(row);
  dataGrid2.ItemsSource = this.datatableobject.DefaultView;
  tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 1;


  foreach (DataRowView rowww in dataGrid2.Items)
  {
    string text = rowww.Row.ItemArray[1].ToString();
    if (text == sid)
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("ALREADY");
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess you want to add braces around the true IF result as in if (text==sid){...} - As coded, it will always perform the return.

Comment: @EmmadKareem am tried that braces also,but it shows always already listed if am add first time also,so am stuck here

Comment: You have to have the braces. I suggest you try to debug.

Comment: @EmmadKareem Am done that braces with debug also,itss shows already listed alltime,because when am add sid to datagrid3,its present there,so that it always tell as the sid==text,want to change that and how to make possible solution

Comment: Why Here downvote??????

Comment: because people think that not much effort was invested in research or debugging this stuff

Comment: if you did debug, try to explain your problem again using better names, I am still confused what is dataGrid3 .. when your first line says you have only 2 grids.

Comment: @Muds  Now am edited the code,now give solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<string> results = new List<string>();
if (results.Contains(sid))
{
  System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Study Already Listed");
  return;
}
```

It must works fine!!!

Answer (score 0):

Read comments

```
public void sendstudy(string sid, DataRow row)       
{ 

  // row added to TableObject
  this.datatableobject.Rows.Add(row);

  // Row added to dataGrid2 - as its the same obj we added row to in last step.
  dataGrid2.ItemsSource = this.datatableobject.DefaultView;
  tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 1;

  // I don't know how many rows are there, or may be you want to iterate on datatableobject instead ?
  foreach (DataRowView rowww in dataGrid2.Items)
  {
    // text will be different for all other rows but the one you added
    string text = rowww.Row.ItemArray[1].ToString();
    // if would set for your row if text mathches
    if (text == sid)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("ALREADY");
        return;
    }
  }
}
```

Now if any rowww.Row.ItemArray[1] is sid, it will show you msgBox else it will not

Comment: its now for you to edit and tell us which of the lines is not correct when you debug and do not miss the braces around if